use of undeclared identifier 'cpPolyShapeGetNumVerts'
I am trying to use cpPolyShapeGetNumVerts on Chipmunk2D 7.X and it seems it was removed.
How can I replace it?

The answer is
  const auto position = cpBodyGetPosition(_props.body.get());
  const int count = cpPolyShapeGetCount(_props.shape.get());

  std::vector<cpVect> vertices(count);
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    vertices[i] = cpPolyShapeGetVert(_props.shape.get(), i);
  }


You tagged your question as C question.
